# a very simple implementation of an onion router

Tags: java, security, encryption

I want to write a very simple implementation of an onion router in Java (but including chaum mixes) - a lot of the public / private key encryption seems pretty straightforward, but struggling to understand how the last router would know that the final onionskin has been 'peeled'.

I was thinking of having some sort of checksum also encoded, so that each router tries a decryption with their private key, and if the checksum works - forwards the newly peeled onion to the next router.

Only this way, (assuming that some bit of the checksum are stripped every time a successful decryption occurs) there will be a way (looking at the checksum) to estimate how close it is to decryption -- this this a major vulnerability ? is the checksum methodology an appropriate simplification?

Comment: This seems more general than java....

Comment: plan to write it in java - so in case there are any specific resources i can use for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrespective of the problem you mention, it's generally good practice to include some integrity check whenever you encrypt/decrypt data. However, checksums aren't really suitable for this. Have a look at Secure Hash algorithms such as SHA-256 (there are implementations built into the standard Java cryptography framework).

Now, coming back to your original question... To each node of the onion, you're going to pass an encrypted "packet", but that packet won't just include the actual data to pass on-- it'll include details of the next node, your hash code, and whatever else... including whatever flag/indication to say whether the next "node" is an onion router or the actual end host. Indeed the data for the last node will have to have some special information, namely the details of the actual end host to communicate with. In other words, the last node knows the onion has been peeled because you encode this fact in the data it ends up receiving.

Or at least, I think that's how I'd do it... ;-)

N.B. The encryption per se isn't that complicated I don't think, but there may be one or two subtleties to be careful of. For example, in a normal single client-server conversation, one subtlety you have to be careful of is to never encrypt the same block of data twice with the same key (or at least, that's what it boils down to-- research "block modes" and "initialisation vectors" if you're not familiar with this concept). In a single client-server conversation the client and server can dictate parts of the initialisation vector. In an onion router, some other solution will have to be found (at worst, using strongly-generated random numbers generated by the client alone, I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the number of checksums by storing them in a cyclic array, whose initial offset is chosen at random when the onion in constructed. Equivalently, you could cyclically shift that array after every decryption.